# How can I login to amazon ec2 with root directly in PuTTY or WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, putty, winscp

1. How can I login to Amazon EC2 with `root` directly in PuTTY??
   Each time I need to `su - root` first and change to `root`... Is there any other ways??
2. How can I login to Amazon EC2 with `root` directly in WinSCP or Filezilla??

Since I want to "push" the file to some directly from my computer, but I cannot do this (e.g. create dir when login with `ec2-user`)

Comment: This is not a programming question, it's a server adminstration question. Those belong on http://www.serverfault.com not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Change the `PermitRootLogin` setting from `no` to `yes` in your `sshd_config` file, then restart your SSH server.

Comment: You really don't want to be doing any of these things as root anyway... I shouldn't have answered.

Comment: but how to transfer local file to server?

Comment: You do not need to be the root user to copy files to the server. Any user with write permission on the destination directory can do so.

Answer (score 3):

When setting up a server, the simplest solution, really, is to just upload the file as root – probably not the best idea from a security perspective, but it really does save a lot of effort when you are copying configuration files back and forth between machines.

On the EC2 instance run:

```
# visudo  (or edit /etc/sudoers)
Comment out Defaults requiretty (line 55) 
(or change to Defaults !requiretty)
```

In WinSCP:

```
Under Session:
Set the username to same username you login with (the default is ec2-user)
Change the File protocol to ‘SCP’
Under Environment > SCP/Shell:
    Change the shell to 'sudo su -' (available in the dropdown)
```

Login and you should find yourself in /root. Once you no long need to use SCP as root, it is advisable to re-enable requiretty.

Source: http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/10/connect-to-amazons-linux-via-winscp-as-root/

Answer (score 1):

2. With WinSCP you should first identify the location of the sftp-server

You can run the following command:

```
find / -name sftp-server
```

In my case, the location was: /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

The previous location should be configured in WinSCP in your session: Advanced Site Setting > SFTP > SFTP Server

```
sudo /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Filezilla to login, and follow the steps below.

To connect to a running Amazon EC2 instance with Filezilla:

1. Edit -> Settings -> Connection -> SFTP
   Click "Add keyfile"
2. Browse to the location of your .pem file and select it.
3. A message box will appear asking your permission to convert the file into ppk format. Click Yes, then give the file a name and store it somewhere.
4. If the new file is shown in the list of Keyfiles, then continue to the next step. If not, then click "Add keyfile..." and select the converted file.
5. File -> Site Manager
6. Add a new site wih the following paramerters:

   Host: Your public dns name of ec2 instance

   Protocol: SFTP

   Logon Type: Normal

   User: ec2-user

Press Connect Button

Video Tutorial: [Click Here](http://y2u.be/e9BDvg42-JI)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: how to log in as root. It only describes how to log in as ec2-user with FileZilla.